# Combine 3 columns (date, time, timezone as VARCHAR) and represent as UTC

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, utc

Due to specific reasons we are storing certain events' dates as 3 separate columns (instead of a single `DATETIME` column):

```
day_begin (column type: date)
hour_begin (column type: time)
timezone (column type: varchar)
```

Here's an example row of data with data for these three columns:

```
2015-01-27
09:00:00
Europe/Rome
```

Based on this information, I would like to do a `SELECT` and get only rows, whose start date is within a specific UTC interval (e.g. only these from UTC start to UTC end of January 2015).

This is quite trivial to do if the time was stored in a single `DATETIME` column, but since we can't change the product to accomodate this specific need - I need to work with what MySQL already gives us as functions to compare to UTC.

Comment: What prevents you from simply converting the time to UTC given the timezone?  It sounds like you think MySQL already has a function for that purpose.

Comment: So all your columns are having the same timezone i.e. `Europe/Rome` ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty No, that's a sample row.

Comment: @downvoter, any particular reason for your action? I couldn't find a suitable answer anywhere in Stackoverflow (Googled as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(CONCAT_WS(" ", day_begin, hour_begin), timezone, "UTC")
```

The function basically concatenates the date and hour columns and uses the value from the `timezone` column as a second parameter for `CONVERT_TZ()` which handles time zone conversions.